# How do I start using Git?

Tags: git

I've been asked to clone a repository and been given a repository address and a public key to access.

e.g. `git@xx.xx.xxx.xxx:myrepo.git` and the public key i've downloaded is in the file `david.pub`

I've downloaded Git.  In the Git directory, there are three application Git Bash, Git CMD and Git GUI.  I don't

How do i access the repository with my public access key? Do i need any other software?

Comment: http://www.git-tower.com/learn/git/ebook/command-line/advanced-topics/ssh-public-keys

Comment: You would have to at least tell us your OS. From " In the Git directory, there are three application Git Bash, Git CMD and Git GUI." I can make a sheer guess you'we downloaded Git for Windows. Is that correct? If yes, you might consider [this guide](http://nathanj.github.io/gitguide/index.html) which suggests using an external SSH client (PuTTY) which might (or might not) be more usable for a Windows user than OpenSSH which GfW bundles.

Comment: I mean, a lot depends on what OS you're using. Including the interpretation of "put your key to `~/.ssh` directory". Please don't force folks excercise in guessing.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this

1. copy .pub file to your `~/.ssh` folder
2. setup git email and name [Link](https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git/)
3. clone the repo using `git clone git@xx.xx.xxx.xxx:myrepo.git`

https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git/

Comment: i have to create a github account?

Comment: thanks, also the first step.  Where is my `~/.ssh` located?

Comment: You only need a GitHub account if the repository is hosted on GitHub. If it's on a private server, you need the administrator to configure your account for public key login.

Comment: @Kristján if .pub file is given to this guy then why do he need to ask admin of private server to configure public key login? he can just add .pub file to .ssh folder and everything should work right ?

Comment: My main point is if the repo isn't on GitHub, telling OP to make a GitHub account is misleading.

Comment: host isn't mentioned so i just made that out also i edited the answer

Comment: I'm downloading GitHub Desktop and then i'll follow your step by step.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: I've done that first two steps but when attempting to clone the repo, i get asked for password?  Is this the server password?  I type in the server password and i get `stdin: is not a tty`,`myrepo.git does not appear to be a git repository`,`fatal: could not read from remote repository`  How do i solve?

Comment: myrepo.git ? i guess you forgot to replace dummy repo url with actual one ?

Comment: I replaced everything with the actual ones?

Comment: How do i access the `.pub`, is the password in the `.pub` or is the password the server password?

Comment: are you being asked about Pass phrase ?

Comment: if yes then you need to get the passphrase for the `.pub` key from the creators of  `.pub` file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96712/discussion-between-neo-xx-and-user892134).

Answer (score -1):

If you don´t know git Bash, you should donwload git tortoise... y easy for use is very friendly.

https://tortoisegit.org/

Comment: ...with one problem: it tries to force a Subversion-like workflow on the user. This might be okay, but at least should be noted clearly.